# How to solve $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{2304\cos x}{(\cos 4x-8\cos 2x+15)^2} \,dx$

Tags: integration

> \begin{equation}
> \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{2304\cos x}{(\cos 4x-8\cos 2x+15)^2} \,dx
> \end{equation}

This is a MCQ question and there are 5 options to choose which are "A.$2\sqrt{3}\pi+9\ln 3$, B.$2\sqrt{7}\pi+8\ln 3$ , C.$2\sqrt{3}\pi+8\ln 3$ , D.$2\sqrt{2}\pi+2\ln 3$, E.Other solution."

How do you solve this integral?

This appears in MCQ test, so I think there should be a trick to solve this without using too much force. The test have 30 questions and 2 hours, so each question should be finished under 4mn ( I doubted it though). Here is my solution that I spend around 3h to solve it. ( Sorry for not using latex and sorry for the inconveniences )[Photo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18kjiesW4x81ZD9WPmOxZNwNluDNycG32/view?usp=drivesdk)

I appreciate any solution tricks. Thanks!

Comment: What is a MCQ question?

Comment: multiple choice question @mrsamy

Comment: I agree, the solution should supposedly not take this much time and space.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess substituting $u=\cos x$ and using partial fraction decomposition will help.

Comment: @ultralegend5385. I think that $u=\sin(x)$ is the good one. The problem is that partial fraction decomposition seems to be a nightmare.

Comment: **Admire** @Quanto's  answer !

Comment: What test is it?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I said I wasn't sure; I just one looked the question and estimated that!

Comment: @user71207 college entrance exam, I've just finished highschool. It is like IIT JEE or sth like that. The test this year will start in 5 days more. I dunno what kind of nightmare awaiting for me.

Comment: My first guess would've been JEE lol. Best of luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few shortcuts. With $t =\sin x$

\begin{equation}
I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{2304\cos x}{(\cos 4x-8\cos 2x+15)^2} \,dx=36\int_0^1 \frac {1}{(t^4+t^2+1)^2}dt\tag1
\end{equation}
Note
$$\left(\frac{t-t^3}{t^4+t^2+1}\right)’
= \frac{t^6+5}{(t^4+t^2+1)^2}-\frac{4}{t^4+t^2+1}
$$
Integrate both sides over $(0,\infty)$

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{4}{t^4+t^2+1}dt &= \int_0^\infty \overset{t\to 1/t} {\frac{t^6}{(t^4+t^2+1)^2} }dt
 + \int_0^\infty \frac{5}{(t^4+t^2+1)^2}dt\\
&= \int_0^1\frac{6}{(t^4+t^2+1)^2}dt +\int_1^\infty \frac{6}{(t^4+t^2+1)^2}dt\tag2
\end{align}

Similarly, integrate over $(0,1)$

\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{4}{t^4+t^2+1}dt=\int_0^1\frac{5}{(t^4+t^2+1)^2}dt +\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{(t^4+t^2+1)^2}dt \tag3
\end{align}
Combine (2) and (3) to obtain
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{dt}{(t^4+t^2+1)^2}= \int_0^1\frac{dt}{t^4+t^2+1}
-\frac14 \int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{t^4+t^2+1}= \frac14\ln3+\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt3}
\end{align}
Plug into (1)
$$I= 9\ln3+ 2\sqrt3{\pi}$$

---

P.S. The last integral is carried out as follows

$$\int \frac{1}{t^4+t^2+1}dt= \frac12 \int\frac{1-t^2}{t^4+t^2+1}dt 
 + \frac12 \int\frac{1+t^2}{t^4+t^2+1}dt \\
= \frac12 \int\frac{d(t+\frac1t)}{(t+\frac1t)^2-1}
 + \frac12 \int\frac{d(t-\frac1t)}{(t-\frac1t)^2+3}
$$

Comment: Nice solution (I shall not compare my monster to this beautiful result).

Answer (score 5):

Tou have done a good work and obtained the correct result.

Trying on my side, using as you did $s=\sin(x)$, we ned with
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{2304\cos x}{(\cos 4x-8\cos 2x+15)^2} \,dx=36 \int_{0}^1  \frac{ds}{ \left(s^4+s^2+1\right)^2}$$

$$s^4+s^2+1=\left(s^2-s+1\right) \left(s^2+s+1\right)$$ Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{1}{ \left(s^4+s^2+1\right)^2}=\frac{1-s}{2 \left(s^2-s+1\right)}+\frac{s+1}{2 \left(s^2+s+1\right)}-$$ $$\frac{s}{4
   \left(s^2-s+1\right)^2}+\frac{s}{4 \left(s^2+s+1\right)^2}$$ The first and the second are not difficult
$$I_1=\int\frac{1-s}{ s^2-s+1}\,ds=-\frac 12\Bigg[\int \frac{2s-1}{ s^2-s+1}ds -\int\frac{ds}{ s^2-s+1}\Bigg]$$
$$I_2=\int\frac{s+1}{s^2+s+1}ds=\frac 12\Bigg[\int \frac{2s+1}{ s^2+s+1}ds -\int\frac{ds}{ s^2+s+1}\Bigg]$$
Now, for the third and fourth antiderivatives which look like
$$J=\int \frac s{(s^2+as+1)^2} ds=\int \frac s{(s-r_1)^2(s-r_2)^2} ds$$ partial fraction decomposition again
$$\frac s{(s-r_1)^2(s-r_2)^2}=\frac{r_1}{(r_2-r_1)^2 (s-r_1)^2}+\frac{r_1+r_2}{(r_2-r_1)^3 (s-r_1)}-$$ $$\frac{r_1+r_2}{(r_2-r_1)^3
   (s-r_2)}+\frac{r_2}{(r_2-r_1)^2 (s-r_2)^2}$$

*This is a pure nightmare !*

At the end, after recombining evrything, the antiderivative is
$$\frac{6 s\left(1-s^2\right)}{s^4+s^2+1}+4 \sqrt{3} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{16 s \left(1-s^2\right)}{3 \sqrt{3}}\right)+9 \log \left(\frac{s^2+s+1}{s^2-s+1}\right)$$ and, for the definite integral, your good result
$$2 \sqrt{3} \pi +9 \log (3)$$

All this work took me more than one hour. Be sure that I have been looking for tricks but ... no one came to my mind.

Comment: +1 for the 1 hour lol, anyways I guess this is not a bigger nightmare than the attached file.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 hahah, I just use everything I could

Comment: @user635988. Me too ! The only difference between you and me is that I used Mathjax (which makes things "looking" cleaner). Again, you did a good job. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici guess this is the forbidden exercise that I shouldn't try to solve it if I meet in my test, otherwise I'd get only 1/30 or 0/30!